# Repeating element after xsd:all

Tags: xml, xsd

I'd like to ask if it possible to allow one element to be repeated after xsd:all. Something like this:

```
<xsd:complexType name="animal">        
    <xsd:all>
        <xsd:element name="name" type="nameType"/>
        <xsd:element name="price" type="salaryType"/>
    </xsd:all>        
    <xsd:element name="note" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

This is not valid because there cannot be an element after xsd:all, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have `element` as a child of `complexType`. You need something like an `all` group inside a `sequence`, but that is also illegal (`all` has to be the top level of the complex type, and it also can't contain groups - only elements and references). So `all` is too restricted to do what you want.

A solution would be not to use `all` but to use a different group and configure it so it behaves like the all group you declared. Here are some alternatives. You can choose one that works for you or experiment a bit and adapt one.

1) A `choice` element allows you to select one from a group. Declaring a `choice` group with `maxOccurs="unbounded"` will give you a similar effect, and you can then nest a `choice` inside a `sequence` obtaining what you expect:

```
<xsd:complexType name="animal">   
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="price" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:choice>
        <xsd:element name="note" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Only one element is selected for the choice, but since you can have many choice groups, the effect will allow you to have many elements in any order. It's not 100% equivalent to `all` though: since there is no `minOccurs` you need to have at least one `price` or one `name`, but it doesn't required both. This will be valid:

```
<price></price>
<name></name>
<name></name>
<name></name>
<price></price>
<name></name>
<price></price>
<price></price>
<note></note>
<note></note>
<note></note>
```

and this:

```
<price></price>
<name></name>
```

but also this:

```
<price></price>
```

and it will fail if there is nothing or only a `note`.

2) If you need to guarantee that *both* are present as a pair, then you need a `sequence`:

```
<xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="price" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="note" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xsd:sequence>
```

This will make validation fail if only a `price` or `name` is present, but it will also fail if `price` comes *before* `name` because it enforces the order.

3) If you want to allow the `name`/`price` pair in *any* order, you can declare a `choice` containing the two `sequences`:

```
<xsd:complexType name="animal">   
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="price" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="price" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:choice>
        <xsd:element name="note" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

But this will allow name/price *pairs* in any order. You still can't have:

```
<price/>
<price/>
<name/>
```

4) If you wan't to allow `names` and `prices` in any order, but also allow unbalanced pairs, and *no* `names` or `prices`, or an empty `animal`, then you could use this:

```
<xsd:element name="animal" type="animal" />
<xsd:complexType name="animal">   
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="price" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:element name="price" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="note" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

None of these are the same as `all` but, depending on your needs, one of them or some combination might fit your needs.